# Is DirectX 12 or lower just an API?

Tags: windows, gpu, directx12

I am programming a game using DirectX 12. Shall it support all GPUs? Or just newer GPUs? What about the version of the Windows OS supported?

What changes when a new DirectX version comes?

Comment: What does the DirectX 12 documentation say about supported hardware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shall it support all GPUs? Or just newer GPUs? What about the version of the Windows OS supported?

From [Nvidia](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3711/%7E/which-nvidia-gpus-will-support-dx12%3F), DirectX12 supports all GPUs using the **Ampere** (RTX 3000 Series), **Turing** (RTX 2000 Series), **Pascal** (GTX 1000 Series), **Maxwell** (GTX 900 Series), **Kepler** (GTX 700 Series) and **Fermi** (GTX 500 Series) architectures, although **4000** series RTX cards should work as well.

It's important to note that where series are missed out (for example **600** and **800** series) they may be using architectures from older generations, for example the GTX **600** Series are actually using the **Kepler** architecture, and the **800** Series are actually only a series of **laptop GPU**, but should still support DirectX12.

On the AMD side, I can't seem to find a definitive answer, but just know that most GPUs in todays age will support it, and **its not worth downgrading to DX11 for the tiny percentage of people that can't play it**.

In terms of **operating system** again, I wouldn't worry, about it, DirectX12 works on Windows 11, 10, 8, and slightly on 7. But as I said before, anyone who plays games will likely already have a decent GPU and will probably be on **Windows 10 or even 11** by now.

> What changes when a new DirectX version comes?

Well, I'm not quite sure what you mean by this one, when a new version comes, it comes. If you're talking about what that will mean for your game, it would mean you're using an older version. But **would you rather wait for them to release a new version?** Probably not it would be a waste of time.

Hopefully that answers your question(s)

Comment: Essentially it's all "Direct3D Feature Level 11.0" or better video cards, but not the older Direct3D 10.x and 10level9 parts which at this point are *extremely* old. For AMD It's AMD "GCN" 1.0 (HD 7700 or later, HD 8000 Series, Radeon R9 270 (X)
, Radeon R9 280 (X), etc.). Intel did support DX12 with Haswell, but yanked support rather than fix it for a security issue.  Everything newer works.

Comment: "its not worth downgrading to DX11 for the tiny percentage of people that can't play it.". Does that mean GPUs were ready for DX12? Are they ready for DX13?

Comment: It means that like 99% of people will have graphics cards that support DX12. I don't know if they're ready for DX13 since it isn't released yet.